# When exporting a jrxml to an excel, why do the numbers not have numeric values?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I'm using openbravo reports, and when I export a report to an excel the numbers inside it don't have any numeric value, so when I select them to make a sum it doesn't work.

Does it have any relation to the type of field I'm using in Jaspersoft?

Comment: Im using jaspersoft studio 6.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First turn on that jasper report should detect cell type [`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type)

Now the result in excel depends on the type that you have in the text fields. It's a common error to format the number in text fields

```
<textField>
     <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="545" height="30" uuid="20cfbb7d-73d5-4d21-bdf4-7e54b2ccf753"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[NumberFormat.getInstance().format(1.23d)]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

This converts the `Number` to a `String` and the export to excel will not work properly.

Instead the **correct solution** is to use **pattern**

```
<textField pattern="#,##0.###;#,##0.###-">
   <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="545" height="30" uuid="20cfbb7d-73d5-4d21-bdf4-7e54b2ccf753"/>
   <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[1.23d]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

This way the export can understand it's a number and know which pattern it should apply when it exports to excel. You can even customize the pattern for excel using the [`net.sf.jasperreports.xls.number.pattern`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.xls.number.pattern) property.

A small example having excel detect the number and using different patterns in excel export. I have also add a couple of properties to make it look more like a normal excel (removing margins, white background etc).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TestRewindableDatasource" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="dc03cf06-2828-447a-9238-63e7ca5bc637">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.background" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.border" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="false"/>
    <title>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00;#,##0.00-">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="260" height="20" uuid="20cfbb7d-73d5-4d21-bdf4-7e54b2ccf753">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern" value="#,##0.#;#,##0.#-"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[10015.231d]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Thats it, just pasted the properties and all worked, apreciated.

Comment: this line works for me: <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>